# Maths for color gradient

Tags: math, colors, gradient

Is any Maths for making a (simple) color gradient?
I'm looking for simple methods of making a gradient. 
Not in a specific language. Just the maths of colors.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)
I was going to answer something really similar to Peter, but adding a (or not) after the 'linear' word. Maybe you don't want a linear gradient. The most important thing is that the function is *[continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)*

Comment: I will use it for programming in the future. But now I need this simple explanation.

Comment: For what its worth, I'm a programmer I see this as being relevant and useful info on how to programmatically transition from one color to another.  I found this page will working with a colleague on doing font anti-aliasing.  I realize it's from 3 years ago but I'd say this was wrongly closed.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Color_Theory/Color_gradient

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, a colour gradient is a linear function for easing from one colour to another. For instance, if you wanted to produce a gradient from red (100%, 0%, 0%) to blue (0%, 0%, 100%), you would sweep each colour value from its initial value to its target value.

[image]

At the middle of the gradient, the colour value would be equal to 50% of the first colour, added to 50% of the second colour. In this example, you'd end up with (50%, 0%, 50%) - which is equal to purple.

Comment: Just a note, many times, in [web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors), the 100% value does not equal to `100` nor `1`, it equals to 255

Comment: Good point - web colours are often represented in 24-bit RGB colour, with 8 bits per channel, from 0x00 to 0xFF (255).

Comment: A gradient is not a "linear function" in *general*. In general it could be any (but probably still monotonic) function.

Comment: @honk, agree, I was going to note it in an answer but since Peter Sobot's answer was so complete I stopped writing. Forgot to note it as you did (;

Comment: What if my colors are neither red nor blue nor green but other colors ?

Comment: To my own comment : I think it doesn't matter; one can just sweep the domain of values the separate one color from the other for R, G and B separately. I'm just not sure that the intermediary colors obtained make the most sense in terms of contrast, saturation, etc. in order for the gradient to have some continuity in those terms

Comment: As far as saturation for example, one can convert the color to HSL and sweep only the hue, leaving the saturation (and lightness) constant. This requires a bit of gymnastics however, as the hue is a circular value. If one cannot use HSL representation and always has to convert back to RGB then this becomes even more difficult.