# How to get a color in a certain point of a linear gradient, in Java / Kotlin / Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, colors, gradient

Before asking my question, let me clarify 2 things first:

1. I am developing an Android app
2. I do not need nor want to draw the gradient. I just want to know the color.

#### Question

I have 2 colors, let's name them `startColor` and `endColor`.

Now please imagine a linear gradient line from `startColor` to `endColor`.

Let's say I have a float `0.3f`.

I want to know at the 30% position, from start to end, the color at the gradient.

How can I do this?

#### Things I have tried

- Java awt library's `GradientPaint` - It is not available in Android context;
- android.graphics.LinearGradient - The best I can do is to get a `Matrix` from this gradient, but then I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22218140/6950238) question and answer.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Oh right that's exactly my question and it applies in all programming language. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You simply linearly interpolate the red, the green, and the blue colors like this:

```
fun pointBetweenColors(from: Float, to: Float, percent: Float): Float =
    from + percent * (to - from)

fun pointBetweenColors(from: Color, to: Color, percent: Float) = 
    Color(
        red = pointBetweenColors(from.red, to.red, percent),
        green = pointBetweenColors(from.green, to.green, percent),
        blue = pointBetweenColors(from.blue, to.blue, percent),
        alpha = pointBetweenColors(from.alpha, to.alpha, percent),
    )
```

where `percent` is a value between 0 and 1