# How to generate a list of 1024 hex color values for a heatmap

Tags: go

I'm a newb that has been working on this little raspberry pi / thermal sensor project in Go.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-a-thermal-camera-with-raspberry-pi-and-go-8f70451ad6a0

The author has a code snippet as shown below that he populated with 1024 values of hex codes from blue to red, however, its apparently only a small portion of all the values I need. Can anyone help me figure out how I can generate the hex colors I need for this purpose?

Here's a snippet:

```
// this is the color heatmap used to display the image, from blue to red
// there are 1024 values

func init() {
    colors = []int{
        0x0000ff, 0x0001ff, 0x0002ff, 0x0003ff, 0x0004ff, 0x0005ff, 0x0006ff, 0x0007ff,
        0x0008ff, 0x0009ff, 0x000aff, 0x000bff, 0x000cff, 0x000dff, 0x000eff, 0x000fff,
        0x0010ff, 0x0011ff, 0x0012ff, 0x0013ff, 0x0014ff, 0x0015ff, 0x0016ff, 0x0017ff,
    ...
  }
```

A friend of mine was trying to help me out, but this isnt exactly right either:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        for i := 0; i < 256; i++ {
                fmt.Printf("0x%06x,", (i*256)*255+0)
     }
}
```

I dont really care how it gets generated (im learning, reading, trying things out) but am really stuck.

Any help will cure my migraine :)

Thanks, 
Adam

Comment: https://github.com/sausheong/thermalcam/blob/master/heatmap.go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the color at a given point on a gradient between two colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218140/calculate-the-color-at-a-given-point-on-a-gradient-between-two-colors)

Comment: Both help, learning! :) thanks folks!