# Get color of element in the point | QML

Tags: qt, qml

I was able to write 'Color Wheel' in QML with *Rectangle* elements:
[image: Color Wheel]

And now I'm wondering how to get color of the handler's position.
I have seen that it's should be possible to achieve with canvas, but may be there is a better solution?
Here the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Item
{
    id: colorWheel
    Rectangle
    {
        id: ring
        color: "transparent"
        implicitWidth: 80
        implicitHeight: implicitWidth

        width: parent.width < parent.height ? parent.width : parent.height
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        border.width: width / 15
        property double wheelRadius: ring.width / 2 - border.width /2

        ConicalGradient
        {
            source: parent
            anchors.fill: parent
            gradient: Gradient
            {
                GradientStop { position: 0; color: "#7FFF00" }
                GradientStop { position: 1; color: "#7FFF00" }
            }
        }

        MouseArea
        {
            id: dragArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
            onPositionChanged: {
                [handler.x, handler.y] = calculatePos(mouseX, mouseY)
            }
            function calculatePos(x, y)
            {
                var vX = x - ring.wheelRadius
                var vY = y - ring.wheelRadius
                var magV = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(vX, 2) + Math.pow(vY, 2)))
                var aX = ring.wheelRadius + vX / magV * ring.wheelRadius
                var aY = ring.wheelRadius + vY / magV * ring.wheelRadius
                return [aX, aY]
            }
        }

        Rectangle
        {
            id: handler
            width: ring.width / 15
            height: width
            radius: ring.width / 30
            border.width: 1
            color: "transparent"
        }
    }
}
```

I was asked to add some more details to be able to post the code:
As you can see I change handler position according mouse position. I want to grab ring's color under handler's position.

Comment: I don't think you can get a point color from  a `Gradient` item. It is possible that the algorithm could be like this: you convert the gradient item into pixmap and then get the color from that.

Comment: @folibis, thanks, I will try that today!

Comment: @folibis I think has the right idea. You can use Item.grabToImage() to capture an image of the Gradient, but it returns it in a call back as a QImage which you can't directly manipulate from QML. You'll need to pass it out to C++ and call QImage::pixel() on it to get the color at a point.

Comment: Also, the math of a gradient isn't really complicated. You could figure out the angle and then do the linear interpolation on your stops to figure out the color at that angle. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12554635/1055722

Comment: Yes, you will need some minimal C++ extension. But I don't think it will take much effort. Create some C++ extension, probably a singleton that take an QML item, do both grabToImage and detectColor, easy as pie.

Comment: thank you for suggestions :) There is still a big question about performance, since I want to read color every 16-20ms and it could be the case that I will have to rewrite entire wheel in C++, that what I would like to avoid, since wanted to separate interface(QML) and app logic(C++) as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have used canvas and it seems that it works well, here the shorten version of the code(didn't include handler logic):

```
Canvas
{
    id: ring
    property double wheelFullRadius: width / 2
    property double borderWidth: wheelFullRadius / 6
    property double wheelInnerRadius: wheelFullRadius - borderWidth / 2

    function getColor()
    {
        return context.getImageData(handler.x, handler.y, 1, 1)
    }

    onPaint:
    {
        var context = getContext('2d')
        context.reset()
        context.arc(ring.wheelFullRadius, ring.wheelFullRadius, ring.wheelInnerRadius,
            0, 2*Math.PI)
        var grd = context.createConicalGradient(
            ring.wheelFullRadius, ring.wheelFullRadius, 0
        )
        grd.addColorStop(0, "#7FFF00" )
        grd.addColorStop(1/12, "#FFFF00" )
        grd.addColorStop(2/12, "#FF7F00" )
        grd.addColorStop(3/12, "#FF0000" )
        grd.addColorStop(4/12, "#FF007F" )
        grd.addColorStop(5/12, "#FF00FF" )
        grd.addColorStop(6/12, "#7F00FF" )
        grd.addColorStop(7/12, "#0000FF" )
        grd.addColorStop(8/12, "#007FFF" )
        grd.addColorStop(9/12, "#00FFFF" )
        grd.addColorStop(10/12, "#00FF7F" )
        grd.addColorStop(11/12, "#00FF00" )
        grd.addColorStop(1, "#7FFF00" )
        context.strokeStyle = grd
        context.lineWidth = ring.borderWidth
        context.stroke()
        handler.update()
    }
    ....
}
```

I still have concerns about performance on mobile devices, but for now it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Math.arc2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) to get mouse angle based on ring center, then use [Qt.hsva](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#hsva-method) or [Qt.hsla](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#hsla-method) methods to get the color at the mouse position.

```
property color color: Qt.hsva(mousearea.angle, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
MouseArea {
    id: mousearea
    anchors.fill: parent
    // angle value is between 0 and 1
    property real angle: Math.atan2(width/2 - mouseX, mouseY - height/2) / 6.2831 + 0.5
}
```

#### Preview

[image]

Here is a circular color picker which I wrote.
<sub>*I used shader effect to create a perfect color wheel*</sub>

#### ColorPicker.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Control {
    id: control
    property real ringWidth: 25
    property real hsvValue: 1.0
    property real hsvSaturation: 1.0
    readonly property color color: Qt.hsva(mousearea.angle, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    contentItem: Item {
        implicitWidth: 175
        implicitHeight: width

        ShaderEffect {
            id: shadereffect
            width: parent.width; height: parent.height
            readonly property real ringWidth: control.ringWidth / width / 2
            readonly property real s: control.hsvSaturation 
            readonly property real v: control.hsvValue

            fragmentShader: "
                #version 330
                varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                uniform highp float qt_Opacity;
                uniform highp float ringWidth;
                uniform highp float s;
                uniform highp float v;

                vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c) {
                    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
                    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
                    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
                }

                void main() {
                    highp vec2 coord = qt_TexCoord0 - vec2(0.5);
                    highp float ring = smoothstep(0, 0.01, -abs(length(coord) - 0.5 + ringWidth) + ringWidth);
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(hsv2rgb(vec3(-atan(coord.x, coord.y) / 6.2831 + 0.5, s, v)),1);
                    gl_FragColor *= ring;
                }"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: indicator
            x: (parent.width - width)/2
            y: control.ringWidth * 0.1

            width: control.ringWidth * 0.8; height: width
            radius: width/2

            color: 'white'
            border {
                width: mousearea.containsPress ? 3 : 1
                color: Qt.lighter(control.color)
                Behavior on width { NumberAnimation { duration: 50 } }
            }

            transform: Rotation {
                angle: mousearea.angle * 360
                origin.x: indicator.width/2
                origin.y: control.availableHeight/2 - indicator.y
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: control.availableWidth * 0.3
            height: width
            radius: width

            color: control.color
            border {
                width: 5
                color: Qt.lighter(control.color, 1.8)
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mousearea
            anchors.fill: parent
            property real angle: Math.atan2(width/2 - mouseX, mouseY - height/2) / 6.2831 + 0.5
        }
    }
}
```